# vim: how to create custom command to indent and then go to next line

Tags: vim, ex

Okay so I want to create a custom command (and place it in my .vimrc file using the :command command, if possible) which basically indents the line which the cursor is on and then moves to the next line. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Why do you want a command to do this? If you are trying to indent a block of text use `<number>>>` (Example `10>>` to indent 10 lines). Or do you want to reindent the whole file `gg=G`? Or you can write a macro to indent the current line and move down one. Creating a command for this seems overkill

Comment: `:Q<CR>` is so much faster and efficient than `>>j`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
 :nnoremap Q >>j
```

This will map `Q` to do what you want.

You can replace `Q` with anything.

You can make the above mapping permanent
by putting it in your `.vimrc` (with no `:` character).

For more info check out `:h map`

Comment: You can use `>>` to indent the current line

Comment: @FDinoff right but I want a code which indents and then goes to the next line

Comment: @jahroy, will the code you provided override the original function of Q?

Comment: @user2719875 - yes, but please check out my edit: you can replace `Q` with anything you want (including control sequences)

Comment: perfect, thanks! On a side note though, if I did put that code in my .vimrc file and override the original function of Q, if I later go and delete that code from the .vimrc file, will my original function for Q come back and will Q start doing what it originally was supposed to do again?

Comment: Yes, deleting that mapping from your `.vimrc` file would restore the default functionality to `Q`.